# OpenVPN on DD-WRT/Linksys E1200 error

Tags: openvpn, router, ipv6

when I try to start the openvpn daemon via SSH command line, I get the following errors:
Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET6
 UDP: Cannot create UDP/UDP6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol (errno=124)

I have IPv6 disabled in the GUI.

My OpenVPN config file:

```
dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
dev tun
proto udp
keepalive 10 120
dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
```

Any idea what to do? It appears to be trying IPv6 but the interface obviously doesn't support it so *crash*.  Not sure how to force openVPN to ignore ipv6 or some other option I need to specify.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't disable IPv6. The days when you could get away with that are pretty much over.

Comment: This is for an aging SCADA system. Ipv6 is not in play.

Comment: Any idea how to correct this error? Why is it trying to use ipv6?

Answer (score 0):

Flashed DD-WRT v3.0 onto Linksys E1200, disabled ipv6, got the same error, enabled ipv6, problem went away.